# WordPress: Customising excerpt inside a widget

Tags: wordpress

I want the ability to customise `the_excerpt` output by removing `read more` link but only if it is inside a widget.

The use case scenario is like this:

In my website users can post their Travel Reports. I am displaying these reports in two ways - `Published` and `Future`. List of `Published` reports come up in a page where I don't want any change in `excerpt` but the `Future` posts come up in a sidebar which is a custom plugin. I want the `excerpt` here as well but without the `read more` link attached to it.

The following function in `functions.php` removes `read more` link by checking `post_type` but from everywhere! I want this link to be visible on normal list.

```
function custom_excerpt_more_link($more){
        global $post;
        if($post->post_type == 'travelog') {
            return '..';
        } else {
            return '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="nofollow">&nbsp;[more]</a>';
        }
    }
```

Is there an option that would tell WordPress to take out this link only if the `excerpt` is being rendered inside a widget?

Hope the screenshot below may be helpful in explaining exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

The `excerpt` with the post entitled My first ever White Christmas – A trip to Manali in December 2013 should have `read more` link while I don't want it for those listed in right side bar. Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**
Modified code:

```
function custom_excerpt_more_link($more){
        if(dynamic_sidebar('upcoming-stories-sidebar')) {
            global $post;
            if ($post->post_type == 'travelog') {
                return '..';
            } else {
                return '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="nofollow">&nbsp;[more]</a>';
            }
        }
        else {
            return '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="nofollow">&nbsp;[more]</a>';
        }
    }

    add_filter('excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more_link');
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you use css display none properties. First find the post wrapper ; let's say the custom post type's wrapper is  `.custom` and its css would be

```
.custom a {
     display:none 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code actually created an infinite loop of upcoming stories inside my content area! And sidebar is not visible. Edited my post with new screenshot and updated code.

Comment: What plugin or codes you are using to generate sidebar post content?

Comment: I am not using any ready made plugin. It's a custom plugin using WP_Query: `$q = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'travelog',
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'post_status' => array('future')
        ));`

Comment: Yes, this is always an option as far as UI is concerned. But it does not hide the URL from rendering and the same is always visible in page view source, which is not desired.